# MongoDB grouping and max item?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to write this query in MongoDB!

I need to return rows from a query where the max "Revision" is the row returned for an item

I have two parts:

1. Return a count without actually getting the data.
2. Return all the data (not necessarily in order by column A but would
   be helpful) based on the grouping.

Here's a sample set (In our real world data, we have ~40 columns and potentially millions of rows):

```
    A       B       C       D       Revision
    --------+-------+-------+-------+------------
    Item1   100     200     300     1
    Item1   111     222     333     2
    Item2   200     500     800     1
    Item2   222     555     888     2
    Item2   223     556     889     3
    Item3   300     600     900     1
    Item4   400     700     1000    1
```

What I need to be returned:

1. The returned count: 4
2. The returned data:

   ```
   A       B       C       D       Revision
   --------+-------+-------+-------+--------
   Item1   111     222     333     2
   Item2   223     556     889     3
   Item3   300     600     900     1
   Item4   400     700     1000    1
   ```

I've been trying so many combination or `$group` and `$count` and even tried to use 
SQL to MongoDB query translation tools but can't seem to make it work.

Please help and thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$A",
      A: { $first: "$A" },
      B: { $max: "$B" },
      C: { $max: "$C" },
      D: { $max: "$D" },
      Revision: { $max: "$Revision" },
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TW-bB9pLycS)

So in the `data` field you'll have actual documents where as count represent no.of unique `'A'`'s in collection.

In other way if you don't want result to be in that way you can just try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$A",
      A: { $first: "$A" },
      B: { $max: "$B" },
      C: { $max: "$C" },
      D: { $max: "$D" },
      Revision: { $max: "$Revision" },
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 },
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NFXVoEfpjMi)

It would return an array of objects cause aggregation will always return a cursor which will be resolved to an array in code then you can just do `.length` on array to get total count instead of using second `$group` stage in first query to get just the total count this is another option to do.

Comment: Thanks.  The queries work.  With your guidance I think I can move forward.